# Android hashMap deserialize

Tags: java, android, apache-mina

I have server written in java SE, and a client is written in android, when I serialize an object `Map` in the client and then I pass it to the server and the server can't deserialize the object and vice versa. So, when I'm trying to deserialize another object like `String`, or `Date`, that's working fine.

Comment: What type of serializing?

Comment: What kind of data is stored in your map?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Map`s should usually be avoided in interfaces, especially when it involves serialization.

Instead, try to replace your map by an other data structure containing the same data.

For instance, create an object like:

```
public class MyObject implements Serializable {
    Key keyOfMap;
    Value valueOfMap;
}
```

And send a `List<MyObject>` or equivalent.

This should avoid all your map problems.

Comment: Thanks. I thought about that.

Comment: but i wonder why the Map don't deserializes, because when I serialize in java SE the server deserializes the object well

Answer (score 1):

HashMap itself is Serializable. The problem is that all keys / values it contains must be Serializable too if you want to serialize this map instance.

Comment: All objects are implements Serializable

Comment: I dont think so. Only classes that implement java.io.Serializable can be serialized with ObjectOutputStream.writeObject